Calculate last 12 months sales and Previous year in DAX
I have a DAX code that works, but now I want to create a new measure so that I can see the same thing for the previous year. This way, I can have two measures with rolling sales in the same graph.
R12 months = 
  VAR MaxDate = LASTDATE(d_date[date])
  VAR MinDate = SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(MaxDate)
  VAR Result =
    CALCULATE(
      [Store sale],
      FILTER(ALL(d_date),
        d_date[date] <= MaxDate &&
        d_date[date] > MinDate)
    )
  RETURN
    Result


I think it would be better to create a flag to indicate whether each record is Current 12 month period or previous. Then use flag as Legend in charts.
